# Getting null on sending values from Servlet to Client-side JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying a simple example of sending values from a servlet `Servlet1.java` to client-side JSP page `client1.jsp`.

But I am getting null
Here is the code `Server1.java`:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;


@WebServlet("/server1")
public class Server1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    String name="Rahul";
    request.setAttribute("myname",name);

    //Servlet JSP communication
    RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/client1.jsp");
    reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);

}
}
```

Code for `client1.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% String s=request.getParameter("myname");%>
    Hello friends <%=s%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are setting an attribute and getting a parameter. Try getting the attribute in your jsp instead.

Comment: I even tried but again it shows null @DanielBarbarian

Comment: So you are using `request.getAttribute("myname")` but that is still null? Are you doing a post request to your servlet?

Comment: Are you getting `Hello friends null` or are you getting a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I am getting Hello friends null

Comment: And you are sure you are doing a POST request to that servlet and not going directly to the jsp page in your browser?

Comment: In other words, what url are you using when you are testing this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much I can't understand you can refer the code please.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/mypro/client1.jsp

Comment: try `localhost:8080/mypro/server1`. Oh and change `doPost` in your servlet code to `doGet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is bad.

First you are mixing *attributes* and *parameters*. They are different animals. Parameters is what comes from the client and are set once by the servlet container. Attributes are objects that are used by cooperating elements (filters, servlets and JSP pages) for passing data.

So you should at least read the attributes in JSP:

```
<% String (String) s=request.getAttribute("myname");%>
```

You must cast the attribute to `String` because `getAttribute` returns an `Object`.

But that's not all. Scriptlets are deprecated for decades, and should only be used for very special use cases, if any. Here, assuming you have a decent servlet container, you could simply use the `${}` JSTL automatic attribute:

```
<body>
    Hello friends ${myname}
</body>
```

It is shorter, cleaner and less error prone.

After your comments, there is another possible problem. You only show the override of `doPost` in your servlet code, when common requests (unless you post from a form) are GET requests and are processed in `doGet`. If you use a GET request and only set the attribute in `doPost` your JSP will not find it...

Comment: Now it is not showing null but also it is not showing value of that string.

Comment: It worked ! I wrote the code in doGet ,changed to getAttribute and thanks for other tips as well

Comment: But It showed only on server page I want it on client page .What should I do?

Comment: @RahulChoubey: I'm sorry by I can't understand. What do you mean by client page? A JSP is translated by the server container in a true servlet, so it can only exists inside a server side web application

Answer (score 1):

"myname" you are setting to request.setAttribute

so, you can retrieve as below:

```
<% String s=(String) request.getAttribute("myname");%>
```

Comment: Still getting null